# how does tor protect data packets?

Tags: tor

When you're using tor can't the third parties copy all the data that's going back to your device and decrypt it later, let's say I downloaded some doc files, the data has to come back to your device through your isp servers right. If your government wants your isp to keep copies of all the data packets to be reviewed later can't they just break the encryption later? I'm sorry if this question sounds stupid but I'm still a noob and I'm using tor from a week.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of encryption is that you *can't* break it. At least, not without a lot of computing power and/or a lot of time (say, 80 years). So, you should be good to go. :-)

Comment: lol sry I don't have much idea about this subject, thx.

Comment: No worries! Cryptography is really confusing stuff.

Comment: Can I learn cryptography, I'm really clever lolol

Comment: Sure! It's a lot of math. I don't know if there's a particularly good book to start with; I'd suggest trying the Matasano crypto challenges, but they've sadly been offline for a while.

Comment: I was just kidding:-)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't make much sense now would it? TOR creates encrypted connections from your pc to an exit node. More technical a key is generated to encrypt the traffic. (every node adds a layer of encryption) The data will arrive encrypted at the ISP server. The longer they wait with decrypting, the smaller the chance exists the key is still around. More precisely every new secure connection you make with TOR will use a new key. So over time the key which was used to encrypt data will be destroyed (removed out of memory), hence no chance in the world to decrypt the data ever again. Unless you consider brute forcing it with a quantum computer, but that's something for the science-fiction books for now. :-)

Comment: Thx, well explained.